# How to get user's home country from hometown id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FB returns `hometown` like this:

```
hometown: {
    id: "106050279435951",
    name: "Quezon City, Philippines"
},
```

How to get country using that `hometown` id? I see that I can get country name form `name: "Quezon City, Philippines"`, but I'm curious if FB Graph API has means to use that `hometown` id to get some special value about country.

Comment: did you check out the api docs? they will tell you about all the available fields.

Comment: @luschn, I'd downvote your comment if SO had this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hometown` field refers to a page, and that page in turn has a location.

```
106050279435951?fields=location
```

Result:

```
{
  "location": {
    "city": "Quezon City",
    "country": "Philippines",
    "latitude": 14.6439,
    "longitude": 121.037
  },
  "id": "106050279435951"
}
```

You can also use Field Expansion to get this info in one go while requesting other user info,

```
me?fields=hometown{location},...
```